# Angular *ngFor with ambiguous dependency on another *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, angular-pipe

I have a Angular html template that has a ambiguous dependency between an observable and a piped function. The output of the functions are the `events` and `schedule$` arrays, respectively.

Problem, the `event` array does not load into the html template unless the `schedule$` array is also loaded with *ngFor, even when the function for `schedule$` (`getCalendar()`) is run with ngOnInit()

Questions:

1. I no longer have a functional need for `schedule$` so want to completely omit that from my code. Currently, I can't do that because the `event` array's items disappear also. **How can I remove the `schedule$` `*ngFor` without impacting `event` `*ngFor`?**
2. What is the root cause of this dependency? Aren't both functions independent?

```
<div class="boxed">
  CalendarEvent Div from getEvents()
<ul *ngFor="let evnt of events">
  <li>Title: {{evnt.title}}</li>
  <li>Start: {{evnt.start}}</li>
  <li>End: {{evnt.end}}</li>
  <li>Creator: {{evnt.created_by}}</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="boxed">
  Schedule Div from  getCalendar()
<ul *ngFor="let event of schedule$ | async | slice:0:1">
  <li>Title: {{event.title}}</li>
  <li>Start: {{event.start}}</li>
  <li>End: {{event.end}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My component module where the functions are defined is:

```
schedule$!: Observable<Schedule[]>;
events: CalendarEvent[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCalendar(),
    this.getEvents()
  }

public getEvents(): any {
    this.apiService.getEvent()
    .subscribe(
    (data: any)  => {
      this.events = data;
      for (let event of this.events) {
        event.start = new Date(event.start);
        event.end = new Date(event.end);

      }
    },
    (err:any) => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('done loading events')
  );
}

public getCalendar(): any {
    this.schedule$ = this.apiService.getCalendar().pipe(tap((dataset: any) =>console.log('getCalendar()', dataset)))
  }
```

The API end points used in these functions is the same

```
public getCalendar(): Observable<Schedule[]> {
    return this.http.get<Schedule[]>(`${this.API_URL}/schedule/`,
            {
              responseType: 'json',
              headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.auth.accessToken}`)
            });
  }

public getEvent(): Observable<CalendarEvent[]> {
    return this.http.get<CalendarEvent[]>(`${this.API_URL}/schedule/`,
            {
              responseType: 'json',
              headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.auth.accessToken}`)
            });
  }
```

The interface are

```
export interface CalendarEvent<MetaType = any> {
    id?: string | number;
    start: Date;
    end: Date;
    title: string;
    color?: EventColor;
    actions?: EventAction[];
    allDay?: boolean;
    cssClass?: string;
    resizable?: {
        beforeStart?: boolean;
        afterEnd?: boolean;
    };
    draggable?: boolean;
    meta?: MetaType;
    isEditable?: boolean;
    created_by?: string;
    event_skaper?: string;
    event_booker?: string;
    
}

export interface Schedule {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    start: Date;
    end: Date;
    created_by: string;
    event_skaper: string;
    event_booker: string;
  }
```

Comment: I have narrowed down the issue to the initialization state. At page load ```this.events``` get initialized only after interaction with one its html trigger's, ie ```next event```, or ```add event``` in lieu of the piped ```schedule$``` also.

Comment: I changed the code several times and am now using the map function to get the api and tried subscribing in the ngOnInit and the constructor, the same issue persists where the template does not render any *ngFor loops at page load.

``` getEventers() { 
    return this.apiService
    .getEvent()
    .pipe(map(
    (data: any) => this.events = data
    ))
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is weird that you have 2 of the same API calls in service that should return different types without any pipes.
Second, I recommend you transform the simple `events` array to `Observable` or `BehaviorSubject.`

so your code will look like this:

```
public events: BehaviorSubject<CalendarEvent[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEvents();
}

public getEvents(): void {
    this.apiService.getEvent()
    .subscribe((data: any)  => {
      // do what you need or want with data
      const mappedData = data.map((event: any) => {
        event.start = new Date(event.start);
        event.end = new Date(event.end);
        return event;
      });
      this.events.next(mappedData);
    },
    (err:any) => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('done loading events')
  );
}
```

after this, simply subscribe to `events` in the template

```
<div class="boxed">
<ul *ngFor="let evnt of events | async">
  <li>Title: {{evnt.title}}</li>
  <li>Start: {{evnt.start}}</li>
  <li>End: {{evnt.end}}</li>
  <li>Creator: {{evnt.created_by}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you help with a more concrete example for what you mean by ```const mappedData = [/*something you need*/]```?

Comment: @EricKumar, I modified my answer. I meant that in your original question, you transformed properties `start` and `end` to the `Date` format. So you can do it before pushing next value to the subject. I am not sure why you need to do it there. If you need to use it in the template, use pipes for these properties. Makes sense?

Comment: I tried this approach, but it led to breakages in other parts of the component.ts, as I use rxjs operators not available with BehaviorSubject.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code several times and am now using the map function to get the data from the API having tried to subscribe in the ngOnInit() and the constructor(); the same issue persists where the template does not render any *ngFor loops at page load. Again the array is presented with console.log() immediately, but it does not show up in the template, until I interact with the template.

I am pretty sure I am not subscribing to the Observable correctly, any tips would help!

```
getEventers() { 
    return this.apiService
    .getEvent()
    .pipe(map(
    (data: any) => this.events = data
    ))
  };
```

```
 ngOnInit(): void {

    this.getEventers().subscribe(
      (data: any)  => {
        this.events = data;
        for (let event of this.events) {
          event.start = new Date(event.start);
          event.end = new Date(event.end);
        }
      },
      (err:any) => console.error(err),
      () => console.log(this.events)
    )
```

Comment: I hacked a solution using the a -1 slice of the the schedule$ call in the template.  Apparently, having a pipe (I think any pipe suffices) instantiates the subscription.